# Keycloak AttributeToRoleMapper with multiple values

Tags: keycloak

My project has a SAML identity provider with multiple roles which we would like to map to a single role in our Keycloak server.

Unfortunately, the isAttributePresent method expects to only have one IdP role mapped and checked in the SAML response.

If you create one mapper for each IdP role mapped to a single role, the login flow will fail after the second login because the mappers are evaluated one by one and if the last one to be evaluated fails, the role is removed.

Mappers:

- mapper1 - IdpRole1 -> KC_ROLE
- mapper2 - IdpRole2 -> KC_ROLE

Users:

- user1 - has IdpRole1, IdpRole2
- user2 - has IdpRole1
- user3 - has IdpRole2

user1:

- first login:

  - importNewUser is called for mapper1, KC_ROLE is associated
  - importNewUser is called for mapper2, KC_ROLE is associated
- second login:

  - updateBrokeredUser is called for mapper1, KC_ROLE is associated
  - updateBrokeredUser is called for mapper2, KC_ROLE is associated

user2:

- first login:

  - importNewUser is called for mapper1, KC_ROLE is associated
  - importNewUser is called for mapper2, KC_ROLE is associated
- second login:

  - updateBrokeredUser is called for mapper1, KC_ROLE is associated
  - updateBrokeredUser is called for mapper2, KC_ROLE is removed

user3:

- first login:

  - importNewUser is called for mapper1, KC_ROLE is associated
  - importNewUser is called for mapper2, KC_ROLE is associated
- second login:

  - updateBrokeredUser is called for mapper1, KC_ROLE is removed
  - updateBrokeredUser is called for mapper2, KC_ROLE is associated

Therefore, user1 and user 3 will have the role, but user2 will not.

Are there any workarounds to this? Is there any plan for supporting multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

As for a possible workaround, you will have to map the roles one by one and then to configure the application with all the needed roles to be granted on it.

Alternatively, you can opt for creating your own mapper that can have multiple values (but this is an extension/integration topic).

Another possible workaround would be to perform a mapping and consolidate the attributes at the intermediate/external SAML IdP level which used for the identity provider federation so that the Keycloak instance only gets a single attribute to map to the realm role in keycloak.